# Complex numbers working with real definition

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

suppose that $z = (x,y)$ and $z^2 = (-1,0)$. Show that $z = i$ or $z = -i$

Now in this form the ordered pairs are defined for the real numbers,

Sonmy idea was by definition of multiplication:

$Z^2 = (x^2 - y^2 , 2xy)  = (-1,0) = z^2$ (by def of question)

Now I wanted to try and manipulate my way to getting $y = 1$, because then I could conclude that if $y = 1$ then $z = (0,1)$ which gives $z = i$.

But that did not work.

I also used a fact that they gave me that $(-1,0) = (0,1)(0,1)$
and tried to say that $z^2 = (x,y)(x,y) = (0,1)(0,1) = (-1,0)$

Then conclude that y has to equal $1$.

Is this the right thing to do?

Answer (score 2):

Just solve the system of equations $x^2-y^2=-1$ and $2xy=0$. From the second one, you have either $x=0$ or $y=0$. But if you have $y=0$ then $x^2=-1$ from the first equation, which is impossible since $x^2\geq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So $x=0$ and $-y^2=-1$, that is, $y=\pm1$, which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: Sometimes it is as simple as it appears. Thsnk you. I have another complex question, but i'll ask it in the forum. Thanks again

Comment: @dc3rd You're welcome.